# SKETCH : How to updade a Button's Symbols but not change the TextLabel's content?

Tags: sketch-app

So that the text can be updated freely without duplicating itself to all button instances?

In other words, the button symbol just retains the styles and not the content.

The closest thing i found was this plugin/technique.. but it seems out-dated : http://brilliantsketch.com/sketch-symbol-plugin-bring-smart-object-sketch/

Comment: found it!

http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/support/documentation/07-symbols/

Exclude Text

A common example of a Symbol will be something like a website header, or footer or common interface elements such as buttons. In all these cases you may want to make an exception for some of text in the symbols; each button should look the same, but its text value should probably be different.

You can easily do this with symbols, by selecting a text layer inside a symbol and checking the Exclude Text Value from Symbol checkbox. Any edits you make to the text are now local to only that instance.

Comment: Yeah, saw that the other day and that was going to be my suggestion..does this method do what you need? Does it not work?

Answer (score 7):

**Symbols - Exclude Text** (from [Sketch documentation](https://www.sketchapp.com/support/documentation/07-symbols/))

You can easily do this with Symbols, by selecting a text layer inside a Symbol and checking the Exclude Text Value from Symbol checkbox. Any edits you make to the text are now local to only that instance.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Just to chime in, Sketch 40 doesn't include the 'Exclude Text Value from Symbol' option.

You can exclude text fields from overridability by locking the text layer within the symbol.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Overrides** panel.

[image: Screenshot of overrides panel]

If you want to learn more about symbols in Sketch, the [documentation](http://www.sketchapp.com/learn/documentation/07-symbols/2-editing-symbols.html) provides a 5-minute video that I can recommend.